# Spring MVC + REST + AngularJs 404 Not Found

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

Facing problem in calling a REST Controller with Json. Getting 404 error. But not able to find the problem. The Controller is defined. No Spelling mistake.

P.S. To use REST do we need configuration in web.xml or servlet-config.xml .
     I have jackson-databind and jax-rs in dependencies.

NewBie in Spring Angular . Need help.

I am trying to call '/addintoexp' controller File

File : expense.js

```
'use strict';

var addexp=angular.module('emsExpenseApp',[ ]);


addexp.controller('addExpCtrl',[ '$scope', '$http', '$location' ,function($scope,$http,$location){  
    console.log("Reached the Angular controller");

    var vm=this;
    vm.expense={};

    vm.expense.expense_name="GROFERS MONTHLY";

    // add-expense button implementation

    vm.submit=function(){
        console.log("Inside Submit Function");
        console.log(vm.expense);
         $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: addintoexp,
             data: vm.expense,
             dataType: 'application/json',
             headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            }).success(function(response) {
                alert(' Success '); 
                console.dir(response); 

                //alert('Success'); 
                // redirect path
                //$location.path('dashboard/users');

            }).error(function(response){ 


                alert('Error');


            });


 }

}]);
```

File: ExpenseController.java

```
package com.ems.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.ems.model.Expense;
import com.ems.model.User;
import com.sun.media.jfxmedia.logging.Logger;
/**
 * 
 * @author Ankit
 *
 * In  this controller , methods like add_expense, del_expense, view_expense, edit_expense
 * all accordingly to the user_id
 *
 *
 *
 */
@RestController
public class ExpenseController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/add-exp", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addExpense(){
        ModelAndView m=new ModelAndView("add-expense");

        return m;
    }


    /*
    @RequestMapping(value="/addintoexp", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addExpense(@RequestParam("exp-name") String expname,
            @RequestParam("exp-desc") String expdesc,
            @RequestParam("exp-amount") String expamount,
            @RequestParam("exp-date") String expdate,
            @RequestParam("exp-notes") String expnotes,
            @RequestParam("exp-category") String expcategory
            ){



        System.out.println(
                " Expense Name : "+expname +
                " Expense Desc : "+expdesc +
                " Expense Amount : " +expamount+
                " Expense Date : "+expdate+
                " Expense Notes : "+expnotes+
                " Expense Category : "+expcategory 



                );

        return "redirect:/add-exp.html";

    }

    */

    //404 Error getting for this controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addintoexp",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> addexpenser(@RequestBody Expense e){

        System.out.println("Inside the Adding Exp Controller. Hurrah. REST is working");
        System.out.println(e.getExpense_name());
        System.out.println(e.getExpense_category());
        System.out.println(e.getExpense_desc());

        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();

        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(header,HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }

    //Rest API Add Expense  
}
```

File: web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>expTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>expTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>  
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

</web-app>
```

File: Servlet-Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

 <mvc:resources location="/static" mapping="/static/**"/>

 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.ems"/> 

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="expenseDaoImpl" class="com.ems.dao.ExpenseDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="loginDaoImpl" class="com.ems.dao.LoginDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exms" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

Comment: You're sending a request using the variable `addintoexp` as URL, but this variable isn't defined anywhere. Open your browser dev tools, and its network panel, and you'll see what and when you're sending. Also, why do you map a servlet supposed to host a RESTful API returning JSON to `*.html`? Finally, upgrade your angularjs version: you're using an old one, because recent ones don't have any success / error methods in HTTP promises. Starting a new project with AngularJS is already a bad idea, but with a old version of AngularJS, it's even worse.

Comment: Changed url in angular to url: 'addintoexp.html'

Comment: But getting 406 error

Comment: i have used jackson for data binding

Comment: What do you want from your REST endpoint? Right now your are sending back a `JSP` view, which is NOT the intention behind REST. With REST you normally send JSON objects representing your domain resources.